# Same model instance for two partial views (ajax)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here's what happens:

1. Partial views A and B show the same model
2. View A changes the data via Ajax (using `Ajax.BeginForm`)
3. View A re-renders itself (controller gets the updated model from the database)
4. Now we have to re-render View B as well, because the data has been changed, right?
5. We get the updated model from the database **again** and re-render View B

How do I prevent re-querying the database? Maybe cache the model-instance in the Session?

What's the "right" way to do this?

```
<!--works great when the page is rendered
    via postback but what about Ajax?--!>
<div>
@Html.Partial(@ViewA", MyModelInstance)
@Html.Partial(@ViewB", MyModelInstance)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create a new partial **View C** that contains both **A** and **B**. Whenever the model changes you have to invoke the action that returns the **View C**.

**UPDATE:**

The other simple solution I see is when **View A** updates the model instead of re-rendering the view, get the updated model through AJAX and the update HTML portions through javascript. If you are using jquery you can use the **template plugin** to update the html quite easily.
By this way you can avoid making one more unnecessary request to update the other **View B**.

Comment: I can't since the Views A and B are located In different parts of the HTML

Comment: So I need to create one razor view in C#, and one JS-view in a template language like Mustache (duplicating the code)... This sucks, bu OK. PS. Gosh I miss webforms + updatepanels SO MUCH...

Comment: I think in case of normal requests Razor or any other server side templates do fine but in case of AJAX requests the JS templates are going to be much helpful compared to partial views.

Comment: But repeating the code is unavoidable if we need the templating should happen at the server side as well